# How can i get a complete list including nested relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, dictionary, associations

I have a task model related to activities and i want to get a array/hash with all Tasks and their related activities like this:

```
<% task_group =[
     ['Task1', {'Activity1' => 1, 'Activity2' => 2}], 
     ['Task2', {'Activity3' => 3, 'Activity4'=> 4}]
    ] %>
```

I came up with `Task.includes(:activities).all.map(&:name)` but this only gives me a list with activities and their name.

How can i get a complete list including nested relations?

My model defintion:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
```

Comment: Why are you doing `.map(&:name)` part, what for?

Comment: I thought i need to use .map to get some kind of array?

Comment: No, to get an array call `.all.to_a`.

Comment: Do you want this: `[ ['Task1', 'Activity1'], ['Task1', 'Activity2'], ['Task2', 'Activity3'], ['Task2', 'Activity3'] ]`? Which structure do you want in the end?

Comment: argh, i have to rtfm. I thought i needed the above structure (task_group) for a group_select. And it is so easy: `f.input :activity_id, :as => :grouped_select, :collection => Task.all, :group_method => :activities`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
Task.includes(:activities).all.map{|t| [t.name, t.activities.inject({}){|H, a| H[a.name] = a.id; H}]}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Task.includes(:activities).all.map{|t| [t.name, t.activities.inject({}){|h, a| h[a.name] = a.id; h}]}
```

Comment: this looks nice, but i got an error 'formal argument cannot be a constant' on this part '|H, a|'